# Template which displays collection does not update automatically after data insertion

Tags: javascript, meteor

After inserting data into a collection the template which displays the collection only shows the newly added data after a refresh. I looked into reactive variables but I am having difficulty understanding how I would use them in this context. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

My code is as follows.

Template Helper

*I make a call to get my orders depending on which template has been selected, I store the results in Session. I return the session variable to be used in the template*

```
Template.ordersTable.helpers({
orders : function () {
    var orderType = Session.get('currentOrderTemplate');
    var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();

    if(orderType == 3) {
        // Return all orders created by logged in user.
        Meteor.call('getOrders', {}, function(err, data) {
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
            Session.set('orders', data);
        });
    } else {
        Meteor.call('getOrders', {orderType : orderType}, function(err, data) {
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
            Session.set('orders', data);
        });
    }
    return Session.get('orders');
}
});
```

Methods

```
Meteor.methods({
'addOrder' : function(order) {
    OrderList.insert(order);
    check(order, Object);
},
'getOrders' : function (filter) {
    check(filter, Object);
    return OrderList.find(filter).fetch();
}
});
```

Any other information needed, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: is there a reason you don't use `find` directly on the client? That would make things a lot easier.

Comment: It would be easier, I was under the impression that we need to keep our database functionality server side for security reasons.

Comment: no, that's not necessary and would, indeed, but into question why to use meteor at all if you don't want to use one of the most central features of it. Just make sure you design your publish and allow rules safely.

Comment: huh, okay. back to the older way I did it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method calls are not a reactive data source. Also, you are making your live unnecessarily hard. Just do the find directly on the client:

```
Template.ordersTable.helpers({
    orders : function () {
        var orderType = Session.get('currentOrderTemplate');
        var currentUserId = Meteor.userId();       
        if (orderType == 3) {
            // Return all orders created by logged in user.
            return OrderList.find({});
        } else {
            return OrderList.find({orderType : orderType});
        }
    }
});
```

Just make sure you have subscribed to the OrderList collection.